# Concatenating a query expression in Azure CLI

Tags: azure-cli, jmespath

I'm trying to query a list of soft-deleted Azure key vaults, then determine if the name of a specific key vault is listed.

```
 keyVaultName=whatever
 az keyvault list-deleted --query "[?contains(name, $keyVaultName)]" -o json
```

That produces the output...

> az keyvault list-deleted: error: argument --query: invalid jmespath_type value: '[?contains(name,**whatever**)]'

So apparently I need to wrap that variable name in single quotes - but how? Is there some sort of string concatenation function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [contains](https://jmespath.org/specification.html?highlight=contain#contains) return true or false, the format is

```
boolean contains(array|string $subject, any $search)
```

You could try this

```
kv=nancykeyvault
az keyvault list-deleted --query "contains([].name,'$kv')"
```

[image]

Or, just wrap the variable in single quotes like this, it by default outputs as the JSON format.

```
az keyvault list-deleted --query "[?contains(name,'$kv')]"
```

[image]